# Convert csv out of json in new coloumn

Tags: json, jq

The below is my json code

```
[
{
    "kind": "user",
    "version": "v2",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "person1"
    },
    "spec": {
      "roles": [
        "access",
        "auditor",
        "editor",
        "abc-access"
      ],
      "status": {
        "is_locked": false,
        "locked_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "recovery_attempt_lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "created_by": {
        "time": "2023-06-07T08:50:58.559675944Z",
        "user": {
          "name": "person2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "user",
    "version": "v2",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "person2"
    },
    "spec": {
      "roles": [
        "access",
        "auditor",
        "editor",
        "abc-access"
      ],
      "status": {
        "is_locked": false,
        "locked_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "recovery_attempt_lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "created_by": {
        "time": "2023-06-06T14:01:15.256905162Z",
        "user": {
          "name": "person5"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "user",
    "version": "v2",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "person3"
    },
    "spec": {
      "roles": [
        "access",
        "auditor",
        "editor",
        "abc-access"
      ],
      "status": {
        "is_locked": false,
        "locked_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "recovery_attempt_lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "created_by": {
        "time": "2023-06-15T12:16:09.35013254Z",
        "user": {
          "name": "person2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "user",
    "version": "v2",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "person3"
    },
    "spec": {
      "roles": [
        "access",
        "auditor",
        "editor",
        "abc-access"
      ],
      "status": {
        "is_locked": false,
        "locked_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "recovery_attempt_lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "created_by": {
        "time": "2023-06-06T13:45:30.543520308Z",
        "user": {
          "name": "person6"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "user",
    "version": "v2",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "person4"
    },
    "spec": {
      "roles": [
        "access",
        "auditor",
        "editor",
        "abc-access"
      ],
      "status": {
        "is_locked": false,
        "locked_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "recovery_attempt_lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "created_by": {
        "time": "2023-06-07T04:49:41.39245724Z",
        "user": {
          "name": "person5"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "user",
    "version": "v2",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "person5"
    },
    "spec": {
      "roles": [
        "access",
        "auditor",
        "editor",
        "abc-access"
      ],
      "traits": {
        "aws_role_arns": null,
        "db_names": null,
        "db_users": null,
        "kubernetes_groups": null,
        "kubernetes_users": null,
        "logins": [
          "ec2-user",
          "root"
        ],
        "windows_logins": null
      },
      "status": {
        "is_locked": false,
        "locked_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "recovery_attempt_lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "created_by": {
        "time": "2023-06-06T13:51:39.173360152Z",
        "user": {
          "name": "person6"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "user",
    "version": "v2",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "person6"
    },
    "spec": {
      "roles": [
        "access",
        "editor",
        "auditor"
      ],
      "traits": {
        "aws_role_arns": null,
        "azure_identities": null,
        "db_names": null,
        "db_roles": null,
        "db_users": null,
        "gcp_service_accounts": null,
        "kubernetes_groups": null,
        "kubernetes_users": null,
        "logins": [
          "root",
          "ubuntu",
          "ec2-user"
        ],
        "windows_logins": null
      },
      "status": {
        "is_locked": false,
        "locked_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "recovery_attempt_lock_expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "created_by": {
        "time": "2023-06-06T13:41:41.579010534Z",
        "user": {
          "name": "xyz"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'm converting it in to csv with

```
jq -r '.[] | [ .metadata.name ] ,  [ .spec.roles[] ] | @csv' ind.json
```

The output of above command in as below

```
"person1"
"alpha","gamma","beta","abc-access"
"person2"
"alpha","gamma","beta","abc-access"
"person3"
"alpha","gamma","beta","abc-access"
"person3"
"alpha","gamma","beta","abc-access"
"person4"
"alpha","gamma","beta","abc-access"
"person5"
"alpha","gamma","beta","abc-access"
"person6"
"alpha","gamma","beta","auditor"
```

I want the name and roles in different coloumn. I want the name and roles in the same line with sufficient space so that if we copy paster in excel, it will be two coloumn, one with "name" and other with "role". Also looking for options if we get output without double quotes

Below is the expected output

```
person1    alpha,gamma,beta,abc-access
person2    alpha,gamma,beta,abc-access
person3    alpha,gamma,beta,abc-access
person3    alpha,gamma,beta,abc-access
person4    alpha,gamma,beta,abc-access
person5    alpha,gamma,beta,abc-access
person6    alpha,gamma,beta,auditor
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the _exact_ output you are expecting from this example so we can know if we are giving you what you need.

Comment: The number of roles varies, how do you want to handle that? Do you want to repeat the name for each role?

Comment: I have updated the expected output. Could you please check

Comment: What is the delimiter between the first and the second column?

Comment: The delimiter is just space between first and second column. @Kusalananda

Comment: You were talking about CSV...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want two tab-delimited columns where the second column is a simple comma-delimited list of strings.

```bash
$ jq -r '["name","roles"], map([.metadata.name, (.spec.roles|join(","))])[] | @tsv' file
name    roles
person1 access,auditor,editor,abc-access
person2 access,auditor,editor,abc-access
person3 access,auditor,editor,abc-access
person3 access,auditor,editor,abc-access
person4 access,auditor,editor,abc-access
person5 access,auditor,editor,abc-access
person6 access,editor,auditor
```

The `jq` expression passes a set of 2-element arrays through `@tvs` to format them for tab-delimited output.  The first such array is the static header, while the rest comes from a `map()` call.  This `map()` call pulls out the name from the `metadata` structure and then creates a simple comma-delimited string from of the roles strings from the `spec` structure.